# How to test and exploit LFI vulnerabilities

Tags: web, web-applications, ctf

I am looking for removing false positives while testing LFI vulnerabilities using automatic scanners
like LFISuite.Any tools and tips that we can use to test for LFI vulnerabilities in endpoints like:

https://example.com/profile?p=FUZZ

https://example.com/index.html?file=FUZZ

Methodology i uses

1. First try to find endpoints that can have potential LFI vulnerabiliites using tools like assetfinder and gf-patterns
2. Second then using LFI Scanners like LFISuite or Burp Intruder to checki for http response code 200 when file is replaced with /etc/passwd or similar payloads
   3.But even if the http response is 200 the result is often some code getting exposed rather than the contents of root directory that can be exploited to get shell or reverse shell.

Looking for some method or tool different from above to try to find LFI vulnerabilities.Any  pointers in terms of pdfs, urls, youtube videos will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the best way is using FFUF. I run it for a few seconds then if i get a lot of useless info back I look at what's common in them. For example, they all might contain 485 words, or a certain number of lines or what have you. I then use the --fw or --fl in those examples i gave to not print out anything that has those values.

A great site to learn more about FUFF's intricacies is: https://codingo.io/tools/ffuf/bounty/2020/09/17/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ffuf.html

Comment: I have used dirsearch and dirhunt a lot but dirsearch gives lot of false positives.ffuf doesn't gives me any fruitful results also.I get lot of urls like: https://example.com/some1/some2/imgone.png like image endpoints.Is there any possiblity of getting an LFI at image endpoint or what are the most common place where we can brute force for getting LFI

Comment: I'm surprised that fuff doesn't give you results that you're expecting. I think this is all down to the word list that you're using. I've got good results using this one: https://github.com/rowbot1/lfi.list/blob/master/list.list